# sbt-assembly: prefix extracted files from some jars

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, jogl, sbt-assembly

In JOGL, there are lots of native jars for different OS x arch combinations. JOGL has several of its own mechanisms to load the right ones if you aren't using java.library.path, and supports a kind of "fat jar" layout.

In a fat jar layout, any native libraries need to be in a subdirectory ./natives/os.and.arch/. However, since the native jars themselves don't have any internal layout, similarly named so/dylib/dll files collide the flat hierarchy in the final jar.

From what I can tell, I don't think I want to de-duplicate with any of the given MergeStrategy because it's only invoked if there is a collision. The layout is mandatory per JOGL's native library loaders - I want to invoke it *every* time. Is there a mechanism that can allow me to map certain jar -> prefix/with/path in sbt-assembly?

### Example

jogl-all-2.1.3-natives-android-armv6.jar is pulled in through a dependency.

```
$ jar -tf jogl-all-2.1.3-natives-linux-amd64.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
libjogl_mobile.so
libnewt.so
```

I'd like this to go here in the final jar:

```
./natives/
./natives/linux.and.amd64/
./natives/linux.and.amd64/libnewt.so
./natives/linux.and.amd64/libjogl_mobile.so
```

Comment: Looks like I missed a passing remark about a function sourceOfFileForMerge, which could be used to find out from which jar a file came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I can tell, I don't think I want to de-duplicate with any of the given MergeStrategy because it's only invoked if there is a collision. The layout is mandatory per JOGL's native library loaders - I want to invoke it every time.

All merge strategies are invoked every time. `MergeStrategy.deduplicate`, which is the default strategy for most files, just happens to take effect only if there's a collision.

`MergeStrategy.rename`, applied for README and license files by default for example, will rename the file every time by appending the jar name.

> Is there a mechanism that can allow me to map certain jar -> prefix/with/path in sbt-assembly?

There's no strategy out of the box that does exactly that, but you can define a custom strategy similar to `MergeStrategy.rename`.

Comment: Well, I've figured it out. I skipped over the remark in the Readme.md regarding custom merge strategies. The key to me is in the included sbtassembly.AssemblyUtils.sourceOfFileForMerge. From that, I can figure out which native jar it was and set the output path accordingly. Like you said, it is similar to MergeStrategy.rename, I just prefix with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this rule as Xerxes explained [here](http://forum.jogamp.org/Packaging-JOGL-projects-to-be-cross-platform-tp4031261p4031286.html). There is then no longer any risk of collision. The [official JogAmp forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/) is a better place to ask questions about all JogAmp APIs. If you don't follow my advice, GlueGen will be unable to extract and load the correct native libraries. In your case, natives/linux-amd64 is correct whereas natives/linux.and.amd64 isn't.